# GUI performance on OS X Mojave

Tags: performance-tuning, mac-os-x, user-interface, system-performance

I am running Mathematica 11.3 on OS X Mojave and experiencing extremely slow GUI performance. Scrolling is worse than controlling Mathematica in Linux KDE over teamviewer half around the world away, typing is also terribly slow, but evaluation seems to be responsive well. Actually, I find it better to run Mathematica under Linux virtual machine.
Is this a standard Mathematica behaviour under OS X?

Comment: No, that's not normal behaviour. It runs nicely for me. MacOS 10.14.2. My front end performance does drop off if I have a lot of graphics displayed. Is this in a fresh notebook?

Comment: I'm running "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" on Mojave 10.14.3 and don't find it slow. Your problem must be elsewhere.